# How can I find Htmlunit rhino version?

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit, rhino

I am using the version of htmlunit 2.56.0.
As soon as JavaScript is executed in Java, the CPU is increasing a lot.
So I want to check the Rhino JavaScript engine version. How can I find it?
Or let me know if you know how to lower the CPU.
Thanks developers!!!

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit uses a customized version of Rhino - you can find the repo here: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-core-js.
As HtmlUnit provides a bunch of patches to rhino the code is in sync with the latest code from the repo.

There are some issues open regarding js code (usually some obfuscated stuff) that shows this effect. If the url of the page is public please open an issue on github and i will try to have a look.

Even better if you can profile this or nail down the problem we are usually  able to fix it or make improve Rhino itself to get this working.